# Un-normalizing PyTorch data

Tags: pytorch

Below code :

```
ux = torch.tensor(np.array([[255,1,255],[255,1,255]])).float()

print(ux)

ux = F.normalize(ux, p=2, dim=1)

print(ux)
```

prints :

```
tensor([[ 255.,    1.,  255.],
        [ 255.,    1.,  255.]])
tensor([[ 0.7071,  0.0028,  0.7071],
        [ 0.7071,  0.0028,  0.7071]])
```

How can I un-normalize the `ux` in order to return to values

```
tensor([[ 255.,    1.,  255.],
        [ 255.,    1.,  255.]])
```

from

```
tensor([[ 0.7071,  0.0028,  0.7071],
        [ 0.7071,  0.0028,  0.7071]])
```

There are various resources that detail this process such as https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/simple-way-to-inverse-normalize-a-batch-of-input-variable/12385/3 but do not detail unnormalizing result of `F.normalize`

Answer (score 2):

`F.normalize` simply divides by the norm according to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=normalize#torch.nn.functional.normalize), so you simply need to multiply it by its magnitude.

This means **you still need access to the magnitude of the original vector `ux`**, otherwise, this is not possible, since *the information about the magnitude cannot be recovered from the normalized vector*.

Here's how this can be done:

```py
# I modified the input to make it more interesting, but you can use any other value
ux = torch.tensor(np.array([[255,1,255],[101,10,123]])).float()

magnitude = ux.norm(p=2, dim=1, keepdim=True)    # NEW
ux = F.normalize(ux, p=2, dim=1)

ux_orig = ux * magnitude                         # NEW

print(ux_orig)
# Outputs:
# tensor([[255.,   1., 255.],
#         [101.,  10., 123.]])
```