# Display examples of augmented images in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, data-augmentation

I want to display some samples of augmented training images.

My transform includes the standard ImageNet `transforms.Normalize` like this:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomRotation(30),
                                       transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                                       transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
```

However, because of the `Normalise`, the images display in weird colours.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785599/un-normalizing-pytorch-data) says I'd need access to the original image, which is difficult when the transforms are applied at load time:

```
image_datasets['train'] = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=train_transforms)
```

How would I go about displaying a few sample augmented images in their usual colours while using the normalised ones for calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I came up with the following:

[image: Example output]

```
# Undo transforms.Normalize
def denormalise(image):
    image = image.numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0)  # PIL images have channel last
    mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    stdd = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
    image = (image * stdd + mean).clip(0, 1)
    return image


example_rows = 2
example_cols = 5

sampler = torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(image_datasets['train'],
                                         num_samples=example_rows * example_cols)

# Get a batch of images and labels  
images, indices = next(iter(sampler)) 

plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 120  # Increase size of pyplot plots

# Show a grid of example images    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(example_rows, example_cols, figsize=(9, 5)) #  sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes = axes.flatten()
for ax, image, index in zip(axes, images, indices):
    ax.imshow(denormalise(image))
    ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.set_title(class_names[index], fontsize=7)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.02, hspace=0)
fig.suptitle('Augmented training set images', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

This is based on [PyTorch's Transfer Learning Tutorial's code](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#visualize-a-few-images) but displays the title above each image and generally looks much nicer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest two options:

1. Create a separate "transformation" stage that displays image and passes it further without a change.  A free bonus is that you can insert in at any stage in the transformation list.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    def TransformShow(name="img", wait=100):
        def transform_show(img):
            cv2.imshow(name, np.array(img))
            cv2.waitKey(wait)
            return img
        return transform_show
```

Insert this "transformer" before `ToTensor()`:

```
                                       transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                       TransformShow("window_name", delay_in_ms),
                                       transforms.ToTensor(),
```

Use zero `delay_in_ms` to wait for a keypress.

I use **OpenCV** here to display images. It can also be done with just Pillow/PIL, but I didn't like how it handles it.

2. Undo normalization and display image.

```
def show_image(img, name="img", wait=100):
    mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
    std =  np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    cv2.imshow(name, img.cpu().numpy().transpose((1,2,0)) * std + mean)
    cv2.waitKey(wait)
```

and then call it as

```
        show_image(data[0], "unaug", 1)
```

3. The last approach can be approximated with a quick two-liner, but with somewhat distorted colors:

```
    cv2.imshow("approx", data[0].cpu().numpy().transpose((1,2,0)) * 0.225 + 0.45)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I find them too high-level to be useful. Given my code, how would you go about (2)?

Answer (score 1):

I already faced the same issue. My solution was to create a different `torch.Dataset` with data augmentation but without normalization.

[Here](https://github.com/fabioperez/skin-data-augmentation/blob/a96ee0c70c8907a05a19cee96710116659685ee1/train.py#L169-L171) I create the `Dataset`. [Here](https://github.com/fabioperez/skin-data-augmentation/blob/a96ee0c70c8907a05a19cee96710116659685ee1/auglib/augmentation/augmentations.py#L70) I have a class that implements the augmentations. I have two members: `self.tf_augment` and `self.tf_transform`. The former only applies data augmentation while the latter applies data augmentation plus normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Just undo the normalization operation i.e. multiply by standard deviation and add 
the mean.

Please see the imshow method in the pytorch tutorials:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#visualize-a-few-images